# How to order a list of tuple first with respect to second element of the tuple and then with respenct to third element of the tuple in python?

Tags: python, list, sorting

Hi all I have a list of tuple like this:

```
L = [(el,3,1),(el2,2,3),(el3,3,2),(el4,2,4),(el5,1,3)]
```

and I would like to order it like this:

```
L_ordered = [(el5,1,3),(el2,2,3),(el4,2,4),(el,3,1),(el3,3,2)]
```

I am ordering first with respect to second number and then with respect to the third number but maintaining the order with respect to the second one.
Someone know how to do that in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `key` argument of the `sort()` or `sorted()` function; have it return a tuple of the fields that should be considered, in the order they should be considered:

```
L = [(el,3,1), (el2,2,3), (el3,3,2), (el4,2,4), (el5,1,3)]

L_ordered = sorted(L, key=lambda item: (item[1], item[2]))
```